# Cannot translate exception message in the theme language pack issue

Tags: magento2

I am trying to translate an exception message from a third-party module from the vendor folder.

This is the code:

```
throw new LocalizedException(__('Custom message'));
```

If I add:

```
"Custom message", "Translate my message"
```

In the `app/design/frontend/vendor/themename/i18n/nl_NL.csv` it doesn't work. However if I add it in the `app/i18n/vendor/nl_NL/nl_NL.csv` folder, it works . Why I cannot add it in theme folder?  Thanks

Comment: possibly redundant question, but still, you deployed the static content after adding the translation to the theme, right?

Comment: @DianaBotean yes, I did :)

Comment: right :) ok, well normally, adding the translation to the theme should have a higher priority than the language packs location. hmm... what theme is your theme inheriting?

Comment: the `<parent>Magento/blank</parent>`

Comment: can you try this, please```"Custom message", "Translate my message", module, <Module_Name>```? i think your theme can't track the custom text unless explicitly pointed out

Comment: @DianaBotean , I already tried that, but without any luck :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128135/discussion-between-attila-naghi-and-diana-botean).

Comment: in my case, Magento has ignored adding the module after the translation as Diana said. I posted my comments below. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It also happens with me. Seems that Magento has a hierarch indeed. What I do?

1. I go for the standard path for translations as you did. If doesn't work
2. I go for the theme or extension path, which I find using the Magento debug mode

From what I could experience, Magento gets data from extensions 1st, loads the content from server, and then, gets the standard translations and uploads everything on screen. Once it doesn't find the sentences to be translated in the .csv of extensions, the content was loaded and doesn't use the sentences on standard .csv.

Answer (score 0):

When adding to the theme folder you need to redeploy according to the theme you are using
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL